# Read array of ints in C

Tags: c, arrays, int, stdin

I need a help with reading from stdin in C something like this:
It is array of ints separated by space like this 32 342 354 231 34.... so I need to read every number into array of ints and I have the number of numbers.

Hope that someone can help,
Sincerely,
Stefan Hacko

Comment: If it is a homework for you, you should try to do it yourself. After you try it, you can write here some codes or something that you thought or tried. This can be more helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how many ints you need to read? Try the [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) function.

Comment: I know but the number is random from 10 to 100000

Comment: If you know how many numbers you need to read, `scanf` works easily. It will retrieve the value of those numbers for you. Try to apply the function to your code.